# Devexpress: Create a dashboad with an oracle data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, web, devexpress

I'm trying to make a web devexpress dashboard using asp.net c#. My data is stored in an oracle database. I can't find the oracle data source in the dashboard creation wizard. I only see local mdf databases. Is there a way to use my oracle data source?

Comment: which visual studio version you are using ?

Comment: visual studio 2017

Comment: Did you instal oracle developer tools for VS2017. If not install ODT from oracle website.